# jQuery >как скрыть первый элемент с динамически формирующимеся последующими

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3

Принцип работы: используется компонент Fabrik на Joomla, в форме есть кнопки `+ / -` для добавления точно такой же формы. Требуется чтоб изначально был только `+`, на всех последующих `+ / -`. Проблема в том, что при нажатии на `+`, происходит полное копирование изначальной формы, то есть если в ней скрыть что-то или прописать стили любым способом, он это тоже скопирует.
Максимум, что удалось сделать, чтоб первый плюс, при нажатии создает как надо `+ / -`, но правильно работает только первый плюс, все последующие создают только кнопку с `+` без `-`.

Код:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.nav-tabs > li').children().each(function(index){

        $('div[id="group-tab1_0_'+index+'"] > .fabrikGroup > .fabrikSubGroup:eq(0) > .fabrikGroupRepeater > .deleteGroup').hide();

    });
}, 100);

$('.addGroup').click(function() {
    $(this).next(".deleteGroup").show();
});
```

Вот этот код полностью копируется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел выход, может можно было придумать, что-то лучше, но если кому пригодится, то вот решение:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.nav-tabs > li').children().each(function(index){
        $('div[id="group-tab1_0_'+index+'"] > .fabrikGroup > .fabrikSubGroup:eq(0) > .fabrikGroupRepeater > .deleteGroup').hide();

        var len = $('div[id="group-tab1_0_'+index+'"] > .fabrikGroup > .fabrikSubGroup > .fabrikGroupRepeater').find('.deleteGroup').length;

        for(var i = 1; i < len; i++){
            $('div[id="group-tab1_0_'+index+'"] > .fabrikGroup > .fabrikSubGroup:eq('+i+') > .fabrikGroupRepeater > .deleteGroup').show();
        }
    });

}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.element_name:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: ни какие из вариантов выбора первого или др. элемента не подходят, т.к. элемент полностью копирует все настройки, `display: none` будет у всех вновь созданных элементов.